# Alternatives to the official (and ugly) Sequential composition

Tags: java, vert.x

In vertx guides, the sequential composition for chaining async calls is shown below:

```
FileSystem fs = vertx.fileSystem();
Future<Void> startFuture = Future.future();

Future<Void> fut1 = Future.future();
fs.createFile("/foo", fut1.completer());

fut1.compose(v -> {
  // When the file is created (fut1), execute this:
  Future<Void> fut2 = Future.future();
  fs.writeFile("/foo", Buffer.buffer(), fut2.completer());
  return fut2;
}).compose(v -> {
          // When the file is written (fut2), execute this:
          fs.move("/foo", "/bar", startFuture.completer());
        },
        // mark startFuture it as failed if any step fails.
        startFuture);
```

Is it just me or is this code really cumbersome and hard to read?

There should be another way without falling into the callback hell. 
It's a pity there are so few blog posts on vertx, any ideas are much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

these days the de facto library for writing asynchronous, non-blocking code on the JVM is [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava). if you're not familiar i'd say it's highly worth your while to take a look as one of the many benefits is the ability to write "flows" as compositional streams that aren't quite as callback hell-y as the JDK's `Future`s were.

luckily, Vert.x is integrated with RxJava. as an example, here is your snippet rewritten using RxJava artifacts:

```
@Override
public void start(Future<Void> startFuture) throws Exception {
    final FileSystem fs = vertx.fileSystem();

    fs.rxCreateFile("/foo")
        .andThen(fs.rxWriteFile("/foo", Buffer.buffer()))
        .andThen(fs.rxMove("/foo", "/bar"))
        .subscribe(
            () -> { 
                startFuture.complete(); 
            },
            error -> {
                startFuture.fail(error);
            }
        );
}
```

much more concise and readable.

note:

- use RxJava 2 as it has [superceded](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0) RxJava 1
- ...both versions, however, are supported in Vert.x, with their respective artifacts living in separate namespaces:

  - `io.vertx.rxjava` for version RxJava 1 artifacts
  - `io.vertx.reactivex` for version RxJava 2 artifacts

hope that helps!